# Please help me to fix the ''list index out of range'' error

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a program to calculate the ratio of minor (under 20 of age) population in each prefecture of Japan and it keeps producing this error: list index out of range, at line 19: ratio =(agerange[1]+agerange[2]+agerange[3]+agerange[4])/population*100.0

Link to csv: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uPSMpgHw0csRx1UgAJzRLit9p6NrztFY

```
f=open("population.csv","r")
header=f.readline()
header=header.rstrip("\r\n")
while True:
    line=f.readline()
    if line=="":
        break
    line=line.rstrip("\r\n")
    field=line.split(sep=",")

    population=0
    ratio=0
    agerange=[ "pref" ]
    for age in range(1, len(field)):
        agerange.append(int(field[age]))
        population+=int(field[age])
        ratio =(agerange[1]+agerange[2]+agerange[3]+agerange[4])/population*100.0
print(field[0],ratio)
```

Comment: The very first time the for loop runs, how many entries are there in `agerange` when it gets to line 19?

Answer (score 0):

On line 17, I assume you to do the following code:

`ratio =(agerange[0]+agerange[1]+agerange[2]+agerange[3])/population*100.0`

next time, write your error more in detail please.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do instead is get the sums of populations in the required age ranges and then perform the ratio calculation.

In Python, you can use the [`map`](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Map,_Filter,_Reduce) function to convert the values in an iterable to ints, and make that into a `list`.

Once you have the list, you can use the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) function on it, or a part of it.

So, I came up with:

```
f = open("population.csv","r")
header = f.readline()
header = header.rstrip("\r\n")

while True:
    line = f.readline()

    if line == "":
        break

    line = line.rstrip("\r\n")
    field = line.split(sep=",")
    popData = list(map(int, field[1:]))

    youngPop = sum(popData[:4])
    oldPop = sum(popData[4:])

    ratio = youngPop / (youngPop + oldPop)

    print(field[0].ljust(12), ratio)

f.close()
```

Which outputs (just showing a portion here):

```
Hokkaido     0.1544532130777903  
Aomori       0.1564945226917058  
Iwate        0.16108452950558214  
Miyagi       0.16831683168316833  
Akita        0.14357429718875503  
Yamagata     0.16515426497277677  
Fukushima    0.16586921850079744
```

<sub>(I don't really know Python, so there could be some "better" or more conventional way.)</sub>

Comment: @ChuYenLy You're welcome :) In case no-one has let you know: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)